# Accessing the methods of a preprocessor name dataset in Progress 4GL

Tags: dataset, preprocessor, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm trying to access the methods of a dataset in Progress, where the dataset is defined as a preprocessor item.  I'm just learning 4GL... maybe this isn't even possible? Here is the scenario in code:

```
/*My Procedure*/
{Receipt/Receipt_ds.i}

def var hReceipt as handle no-undo.
def var hDataSet as handle no-undo.

run Receipt/Receipt.p persistent set hReceipt.
run GetData in hReceipt ({&input-output_dataset_ReceiptDataSet}).
/* do some stuff */

/* get the handle to the dataset???  Obvious syntax issue here. */
hDataSet = DATASET {&input-output_dataset_ReceiptDataSet}:HANDLE.

/* Empty the DataSet (this is what I want to do)*/
hDataSet:EMPTY-DATASET().
```

and here's my include file:

```
/*Receipt/Recipt_ds.i*/
define dataset ReceiptDataSet for
ttRcvHead,
ttRcvDtl,
data-relation for ttRcvHead, ttRcvDtl relation-fields(
stuff, stuff
).
&global-define input-output_dataset_ReceiptDataSet input-output dataset ReceiptDataSet
```

Clearly my code does not have the correct syntax as mentioned in my comment.  Does anyone know what the right way of doing this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece:

```
   hDataSet = DATASET {&input-output_dataset_ReceiptDataSet}:HANDLE
```

is doing this:

```
   hDataSet = DATASET input-output dataset ReceiptDataSet:HANDLE
```

which isn't working as you've discerned. You need to get to this form instead:

```
   hDataSet = DATASET ReceiptDataSet:HANDLE
```

If you put a

```
   &GLOBAL-DEFINE pdsName ReceiptDataSet
```

in your include file and then referenced that where appropriate, then this construct would work:

```
   hDataSet = DATASET {&pdsName}:HANDLE
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to define a pre-processor **before** you attempt to use it.

Not at the end of the file.

The next thing that comes to mind is **why**?  Why are you trying to use a pre-processor for this purpose?  It clearly isn't to make the code any shorter or more understandable.  One reason might be because your code snippet is some sort of common template but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Since he's only allowed to have one page for the question, I inferred that this comment /*Receipt/Recipt_ds.i*/ meant that he had the preprocessor stuff in another file of that name, which is then referenced at the top of his main program.

Comment: I'm taking the code at face value and he explicitly defines it at the bottom of the code sample.  If the contents of the include file are important then they should be disclosed.

Comment: What does "only allowed to have one page" mean and why would it be relevant?  You can have multiple code blocks in the text of a question -- that would be a simple way to show both bits of code if they both matter.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP didn't know that, so I've edited the question to make the distinction explicit